# How to map over an object with an array inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map over an array of comments. These comments are passed into my CommentList components from my LocationShowPage as seen below.

```
const CommentList = ({ user, comments }) => {
  let commentTiles = ''
  console.log({comments})
  commentTiles = comments.map(comment => {
    return (
      <CommentTile
        key={comment.id}
        comment={comment}
        user={user}
      />
    )
  })
```

My understanding was I was doing object destructuring already so I'm unsure why this isn't working as I've done it this exact same way in a different app where it was reviews instead of comments.

```
<CommentList comments={location.comments} user={user} />
```

Above is how its being passed into my CommentList component.

I was expecting it to get passed in as a normal array of string comments but it's coming in as a object with a key value pair value being the array.

```
{comments: Array(2)}
  comments: Array(2)
    0: "test"
    1: "test2"
    length: 2
```

I'm still learning so any help or insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `comments` passed to the `CommentList` component is an array of string but you are trying to access an `id` property on this string to set the `key`. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting mistake :)

1. You are using `comment.id`, but `id` doesn't exist (probably)
2. Your `console.log({comments})` misleads you. You probably want `console.log(comments)`

### 1. `comment.id`

As Oluwafemi Sule pointed out, you are using `key={ comment.id }`, but you said your array contains only strings, so `comment` probably doesn't have a property `id`.

### 2. `console.log({comments})`

The line `console.log({comments})` doesn't just log the comments array, as you apparently expected (maybe it was just a typo ?).

Instead it creates a new object `{ comments: comments }` and logs that new object.

The *expression* `{ comments }` creates an object using the [Shorthand property definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions).

*(Note: The ["Object initializer expression"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) is not to be confused with a ["block statement"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), which is something completely different)*